# How to find tag is parent elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="plp-product">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="../../../kay/images/PLP/jared_000.jpg" />
    <small class="more-options">More options available</small>
    <h3>Neil Lane Engagement Ring 1 3/8 ct tw Diamonds 14K White Gold</h3>
    <h4 class="price">$4,299.00</h4>
    <h4 class="price price--sale"> </h4>
    <a href="#" class="button--quick-view"> <span class="icon-search"></span> Quick View</a>
    <label class="compare-button">
      <input type="checkbox" id="item1" class="chk" onclick="getImg(this)">Compare</label>
  </a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  var getImg = function(val){
     var data = document.getElementById(val.id).parentElement.parentElement;
         data.find('img');}
```

I want access the img tag in data. Not able to find a workaround for this.Please help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: you should rename `this` to something else. (Inside your method)

Comment: You have a lot of broken markup in here. Try fixing that first (img tag is missing a quote for example).

Comment: @HanletEscaño I will do that for sure. Can you help me on my problem.

Comment: what is the problem, are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: yes, the error is, data.find is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code in pure JavaScript.
It traverse the DOM tree to get from the checkbox to an image element.

```js
var getImg = function(ele){
  var anch = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
  var img  = anch.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  alert(img.src);
}
```

```html
<div class="plp-product">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="../../../kay/images/PLP/jared_000.jpg" />
    <small class="more-options">More options available</small>
    <h3>Neil Lane Engagement Ring 1 3/8 ct tw Diamonds 14K White Gold</h3>
    <h4 class="price">$4,299.00</h4>
    <h4 class="price price--sale"> </h4>
    <a href="#" class="button--quick-view">
      <span class="icon-search"></span> Quick View
    </a>
    <label class="compare-button">
      <input type="checkbox"
          id="item1"
          class="chk"
          onclick="getImg(this)">Compare
    </label>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it seems working for me. But how to get img src.

Comment: your solution assume that the HTML will never change, what if he add an element between `<div class="plp-product">` and  `<a  href="#">`, also, some browser might add a text-node (for the space in the indentation) in between  and break your answer

Comment: It has been corrected to a better version. Please notice that I labeled the solution as a `sample code` so it can be improved later on.

Comment: @Ved The image `src` attribute value is printed in `alert`. Do you want to do anything more with it?

Comment: Thanks maxzoom. Let me test it.

Comment: Thanks Ved. In jQuery it will be much shorter `var img = $(ele).parent().siblings('img:first');`

Answer (score 0):

`data` is not a jquery object (since you got it with a native function) and thus does not have the `find` method.
so instead of

```
data.find("img");
```

try

```
$(data).find("img");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this will be some generated markup and that there are many products on the same page.

My solution would be to simply add some sort of id to the img element and then reference that in the on-click event. That way if you change the structure of the HTML in the future it the click wont break.

```
<div class="plp-product">
  <a href="#" id="product_id" >
    <img id="product_id_img" src="../../../kay/images/PLP/jared_000.jpg" />
    <small class="more-options">More options available</small>
    <h3>Neil Lane Engagement Ring 1 3/8 ct tw Diamonds 14K White Gold</h3>
    <h4 class="price">$4,299.00</h4>
    <h4 class="price price--sale"> </h4>
    <a href="#" class="button--quick-view"> <span class="icon-search"></span> Quick View</a>
    <label class="compare-button">
      <input type="checkbox" id="item1" class="chk" onclick="getImg(product_id)">Compare</label>
  </a>
</div>
```

Then in the click function:

```
var getImg = function(productid)
{
     var img = document.getElementById(productid + "_img");
}
```